# How to have multiple replies in posting app?

Tags: php, database-design, mysqli

this is a simple question.

With PHP and MySQL, I'm trying to build a bug reporting application.

Currently, the user can post bugs and a list of bugs is portrayed to the technician/administrator.

How do I make it so that many technician or administrators can reply to the report (thread?)

As in both mysql table layout and PHP coding?

The current MySQL table has layout of:

```
id          (Bug ID)
by          (person reporting it)
title       (Report Title)
content     (Contents of Report)
datetime    (Date/Time of report)
application (Application/page where problems happens)
priority    (Priority)
assigned    (Assigned To)
status      (Status of report/bug)
```

So no response column yet, but how do I achieve multiple post/responses with PHP and MySQLi?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you usually do is you create a separate table for the responses. In that table you have one field that "points" to the first table. It could look like this:

```
TABLE responses
id         (Unique id)
bug_id     ("Pointer" to which bug this response "belongs to")
body       (Contents of response)
```

This way you can have many responses which all point back to one bug, and thus you have virtually created an "ownership" or "relation". It is customary to call a relation like the one above a "one to many" if we pretend we're in the bugs table, looking out. (And a "many to one" of we're in the responses table, looking back at the bugs table.)

Then, in PHP, when you want to retrieve all the responses belonging to a bug, you do something like this: (pseudo code)

```
$bug = SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE id = $some_id
$resps = SELECT * FROM responses WHERE bug_id = $bug['id'] ORDER BY created_at
```

Voilá! Now you have the bug and all of its responses, ordered by creation date. When you insert new responses you need to set `bug_id` to the appropriate value, of course.

Cheers!

Comment: created_at? In my responses table that'd be date.

Comment: date, sure! created_at = short for created_at_date. All matter of taste!

Answer (score 5):

This would be a many-to-one relationship.  You can either have:

response table

```
id (response id)
bugid (bug id)
columns related to the response
```

or

response table

```
id (response id)
columns related to the response
```

with

bugresponse table

```
responseid (response id)
bugid (bug id)
columns related to the bug-response relationship
```

where the second design can also handle many-to-many relationship (unlikely to be necessary in this case) and can also has some other benefits depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You make another table with the responses. For instance with the layout

```
id (Response Id), 
responseTo (id of the Bug this is a response to),
by (person responding),
content (Contents of Response)
```

Where responeTo is the crucial field. Then when you want to view all the response to a bug you just select from the response table where responseTo = currentBugId.